# Java Nullpointer exception on Activity start

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am creating to create a AlertDialog to be displayed which I am doing by creating an activity. Here is the full code, manifest and the error trace. Can anyone please say the error that I am making.

```
// From a service
Intent intent = new Intent( this, Myclass.class  );
intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
intent.putExtra("TYPE", "ASToContainer");
startActivity( intent );

// Activity
public class Myactivity extends Activity
{
@Override
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

    String type = savedInstanceState.getString("TYPE");

    if( type.equalsIgnoreCase("ASToContainer"))
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder( Myactivity.this );
        builder.setMessage( R.string.SWITCH_ACTIVESYNC_TO_WORKSPACE );
        builder.setIcon( R.drawable.icon );
        builder.setCancelable( false );
        builder.setTitle( R.string.SWITCH_AS_CONFIRMATION);
        builder.setPositiveButton( R.string.DIALOG_YES, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int which ) 
            {
                AnotherService serviceInstance = AnotherService.getInstance();
                if( serviceInstance != null )
                {
                    serviceinstance._SwitchASToContainerRejected = 1;
                    serviceInstance.requestClearActiveSyncRegistration();
                }
            }           
        } )
        .setNegativeButton( R.string.DIALOG_NO, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int which ) 
            {
                AnotherService.getInstance()._SwitchASToContainerRejected = 0;      
            }           
        } );
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
}
}

// Manifest
<android:name="mypackagename.activity.Myactivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"></activity>

// trace


07-24 16:30:04.877: C/Myapp(619): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.IMC}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-24 16:30:04.877: C/Myapp(619):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
07-24 16:30:04.877: C/Myapp(619):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-24 16:30:04.877: C/Myapp(619):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-24 16:30:04.877: C/Myapp(619):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-24 16:30:04.877: C/Myapp(619):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-24 16:30:04.877: C/Myapp(619):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-24 16:30:04.877: C/Myapp(619):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-24 16:30:04.877: C/Myapp(619):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-24 16:30:04.877: C/Myapp(619):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-24 16:30:04.877: C/Myapp(619):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-24 16:30:04.877: C/Myapp(619):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-24 16:30:04.877: C/Myapp(619):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-24 16:30:04.877: C/Myapp(619): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-24 16:30:04.877: C/Myapp(619):  at com.example.myapp.IMC.onCreate(IMC.java:57)
07-24 16:30:04.877: C/Myapp(619):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-24 16:30:04.877: C/Myapp(619):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

What I am doing wrong ? Is this the right way to create a Dialog prompt ? Please help me

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.myapp.IMC.onCreate(IMC.java:57) <- there is your issue.

Comment: And it's supposed to be `String type = getIntent.getStringExtra("TYPE")`.

Comment: It is probably String type = savedInstantState... because you don't check if it null before trying to get a string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is "Activity Name".

Intent intent = new Intent( this, Myclass.class  ); //You used

But you are using "Myactivity"

From service you are calling activity name "Myclass" but your activity name is "Myactivity". Thatswhy it is throwing Nullpointerexception. Because it is unable to find class/activity name "Myclass".

So change that Myclass name to Myactivity. It will solve the problem.